# How do I analyse proportion data when the response can be slightly greater than 1 or less than 0

Tags: distributions, proportion

We routinely examine than fluorescence of leaves (using a technique called PAMMING - pulse amplitude modulation), with the response being measured as a true proportion (between 0 and 1) i.e (Fm-F0)/Fm. Both Fm and F0 vary with each measurement. However we do this at two time points, T0 and T1 (before and after stress exposure), and compare the T1 sample against the T0 control to see if there was a change in the response ie T1/T0. Since the proportion can increase or decrease over time, this means some values can be greater than 1 or less than 0.

Any ideas on how to tackle this type of analysis?

Edit: With some more thought, and based on a comment below- I think comparing T0 realtive to T1 by T1/T0 is the issue, and it would be better to simply include 'time' as an factor in the betaregression equation (suitable for proportional data)
i.e betareg(proportion ~ treatment * time)

Tom

Comment: How is $(F_m-F_0)/F_0$ a proportion?  It looks like a percentage change to me...

Comment: Looks like OP has $F_m$ on the denominator (but the point still stands).

Comment: What is being measured?  The values $F_0$ and $F_m$ or the ratios $(F_m-F_0)/F_m$? This makes a huge difference, because the errors in a ratio of correlated measurements (the latter) can be expected to behave much differently than the errors of independent measurements.  Thus, any reasonable, well-supported answer must be based (at least in part) on this consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the OP as having the data points $F_m$, $F_0$ and $F_1$, yielding

> $T0 = (F_m-F_0) / F_m$

and

> $T1 = (F_m-F_1) / F_m$

If that is the case, $S_{A_{leaf}} =T1 \div T0$ makes a kind of slope, which can be compared to other slopes using hypothesis testing.

In other words, assert that $S_{A_{leaf}}=S_{B_{leaf}}$ and do something like a t-test to determine if you hypothesis holds true.